# Is there anyway to save data from the Android Studio memory profiler over time?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

So I know I can get a hprof dump from Android Studio, however it's boring watching over time how memory usage changes and would love a way to get this data exported over time so I can analyze it elsewhere either with R or Excel.

Does anyone know a way to save memory profile data over time without having to manually save sections?[image]